# $q service - should I use CommonJS-style or constructor-style in new AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS documentation for `$q` service says that `$q` can be used in two fashions - `constructor-style` and `CommonJS-style`, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Nevertheless, it doesn't mention whether both fashions are equal, or whether one is preferred. Are those two uses equal, or is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 style is a new standard and I would expect it to become a preferred way of declaration in future. I'd stick to this one in new projects. However, according to documentation:

> progress/notify callbacks are not currently supported via the
>   ES6-style interface.

So if you can live without those, use constructor-style. If not, use the standard syntax.